# Advice on using a Chromebook 14 for development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I am preparing to start taking the Odin Project curriculum for web development. Part of the requirements are to download: Ruby Interpreter, Git version control, Heroku tools, Ruby Gems, Rails Gem, and Ruby on Rails.

I've read several articles from developers using chromebooks advising to set the laptop to development mode. Being a novice in this field, I'm hesitant to jump to anything that would altar my Chromebook 14 without fully understanding the risks and benefits.

Can anyone advise? Should I do this? And if so, what do I need to know to better understand?

Comment: Crouton (https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton) is pretty actively developed and easily installed, though as mentioned, Nitrous.io or Codenvy provide pretty good online experiences.

Answer (score 4):

Long-term you'll probably want to install Linux on it. Meanwhile, you can use online IDEs like Codenvy and Nitrous.io to start coding.

Comment: Thanks for the feeback. I'll enable developer mode soon. Can you advise on what changes when it's in developer mode? In other words, what are the security risks I will need to be aware of? Just trying to get a full picture. Thanks.

Comment: Nitrous has a native chrome application you can use as well: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nitrous-pro/efdcneeepllhjlbejkfnaolelbpdacai